# Using the RWD theme, how do I add currency switcher to the language container

Tags: magento-1.9, multicurrency

I can already see that in header.phtml template it says

`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('currency_switcher'); ?>`

but it isn't visible? How do I make it appear?

Comment: Have you activated multiple currencies properly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `currency_switcher` block as child block of `store_language`.

So open **directory.xml** and add this code between *`<default>..</default>`*

```
<reference name="store_language">
            <block type="directory/currency" name="store_language_currency" as="store_language_currency" template="directory/currency.phtml"/>
        </reference>
```

Then using call this block at *page/switch/languages.phtml*  usin below code:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_language_currency') ?>
```

Comment: These files do not exist in my magneto installation. Languages.phtml in the switch folder isn't a thing

Comment: Found them in Base

Comment: Please copy  those from base to rwd theme.

Comment: Directory xml or local xml?

Comment: If you have `local.xml` at `app/desing/frontend/rwd/default/layout/` folder then just add

Comment: Where do you put the php in languages.phtml?

Comment: have using default rwd theme?

Comment: i am using my own copy of the rwd theme, my question is simple. Where in languages.phtml do you add the line of php?

Comment: Your tutorial didn't work